# Where are added words of Mathematica spell-checker saved?

Tags: spellchecker

In Mathematica 11 it is possible to add a word to the dictionary if the spell-checker does not know it. I did this a lot during the last years. Now I have a new computer system and want to transfer the modifikations of the dictionary to my new computer system. But unfortunately I do not know where (in which file) Mathematica stores these modifications.

Comment: Try `PacletFind["*Spelling*"][[1]]["Location"]` or the things on `Options[$FrontEndSession, SpellingDictionariesPath]`

Comment: @b3m2a1: Thank you! This finds me the place where the built in dictionarys are. But I think it is not the place where the user words are saved. I tried it by adding one word to the dictionary. Unfortunately non of the files in this location changed.